# Add length of following line to current line in bash

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have a small sample data set `test1.faa`

```
>PROKKA_00001_A1@hypothetical@protein
MTIALHLTAVLAFAALAGCGANDSDPGPGGVTVSEARALDQAAEMLEKRGRSPADENAEQAERLRREQAQARTPGQPPEQALQQDGASAPE
>PROKKA_00002_A1@Cystathionine@beta-lyase
MHRFGGMVTAILKGGLDDARRFLERCELFALAESLGGVESLIEHPAIMTHASVPREIREALGISDGLVRLSVGIEDADDLLAELETALA
>PROKKA_00003_A1@hypothetical@protein
MVPIVSAAPVFTLLLTVAVFRRERLTAGRIAAVAVVVPSVILIALGH
```

and I would like to add the length of the following line to the headerline, followed by next line, such as

```
>PROKKA_00001_A1@hypothetical@protein_92
MTIALHLTAVLAFAALAGCGANDSDPGPGGVTVSEARALDQAAEMLEKRGRSPADENAEQAERLRREQAQARTPGQPPEQALQQDGASAPE
```

I tried to do this with awk, but it returns the following error:

```
awk: >PROKKA_00001_A1@hypothetical@protein: No such file or directory
```

I assume it is related to the `>`in the beginning? But I need it in the output file.

This is the code I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat test1.faa | while read line
do
  headerline=$(awk '/>/{print $0}' $line)
  echo -e "this is the headerline \n ${headerline}"
  fastaline=$(awk '!/>/{print $0}' $line)
  echo -e "this is the fastaline \n ${fastaline}"
  fastaline_length=$(awk -v linelength=$fastaline '{print length(linelength)}')
  echo -e "this is length of fastaline \n ${fastaline_length}"
  echo "${headerline}_${fastaline_length}"
  echo $fastaline
done
```

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following(considering that your actual Input_file is same as shown sample).

```
awk '/^>/{value=$0;next} {print value"_"length($0) ORS $0;value=""}' Input_file
```

Comment: well I know what to do, but as you have answered so fast, I have to wait 5 minutes until I can accept an answer

Answer (score 1):

this awk command would do what you want

```
awk '
    /^>/ {
        getline next_line
        print $0 "_" length(next_line)
        print next_line
    }
' test1.faa
```

Comment: That will fail in interesting ways when getline fails. It's the wrong approach implemented the wrong way. See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for the issues with this answer and then see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52097531/1745001 for how to really do this.